# Javascript Promises: testing error scenario

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, asynchronous, es6-promise

How do I test a promise that rejects with an error? (that is the expected behaviour)

I can not figure out why this test is failing. I'm catching the error rejected, and the test still fails. From the example provided at https://www.sitepoint.com/promises-in-javascript-unit-tests-the-definitive-guide/ this should work, and can't figure out how it's supposed to really. Both console logs appear.

```
    it('shows that even an error occurs the test passes', (done) => {
      const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log('error promise is called');
        setTimeout(() => {
          reject(new Error('dummy error thrown'));
        }, 100);
      })

      promise.then(() => {});

      promise.catch((e) => {
        console.log('error caught');
        done();
      });
    });
```

```
1) promise behaviour in tests (async) -  base test cases shows that even an error occurs the test passes:
     Uncaught Error: dummy error thrown
      at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (test\promise-spec.js:24:17)
```

Tried like this, still fail

```
      promise
        .then(() => {})
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log('error caught');
          done();
        });
```

Comment: Your promise should always either `resolve` or `reject`.

Comment: It should work, there must be something that is not in your example. Check this snipped http://jsfiddle.net/scy4pvfn/1/

Comment: weeeeird how does it pass there but at me. @GauravSharma that I think is true here, it always rejects

Comment: Not sure how are you setting up your environment but you are using it correctly

Comment: Which node version are you using?

Comment: yeah turns out it was an error thrown from a different test. <3 async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was because of a previous test that didn't call done, and it throwing an error killed this one